# I asked a question, realized it had a glitch that would take time to fix so I deleted it, now I want to fix it but I can't find it

Tags: support

Is there any way to retrieve the deleted question? Or did I just do something really stupid.

I was hoping to edit the question to fix it before undeleting it.

Comment: If you click on Questions in your Activity page and scroll down to the bottom there is a link "Deleted questions" which might do the trick.

Comment: I believe you will need to undelete the Question before you edit it.  This was a change some time ago because otherwise the changes would potentially go without drawing the attention of the Community (potentially inviting misuse of such edits to introduce spam, etc.).

Comment: You can also search for it in the usual search box, if you include `deleted:1`.